# php - filter_var() expects 3 arguments max

Tags: php, filter

I'm using `filter_var()` over my strings to sanitize them.

```
return filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_AMP);
```

`filter_var()` takes at most 3 arguments, but it gives so many options and I WANT ALL OF THEM!!!

How do I do this properly? The examples here: http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php don't seem to use more than one at a time.

Surely someone must have wanted to strip both ASCII<32 and ASCII>127 without calling `filter_var()` twice at some point, right? Is it as simple as doing FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW & FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH? Or maybe using a bitwise or?

Answer (score 4):

They're bit flags - if you want to use multiple flags, you have to bitwise-OR them into a single value:

```
filter_vars($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, flag1 | flag2 | .... | flagN)
                                                ^-------^---etc...
```